Mean free path equation for plasma
Does the mean free path equation
$$\lambda=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\pi d^2 n_v}$$
work for collisions in plasma or just for gas?

I would suggest adding definitions to your question otherwise it will likely get dinged by folks (it also helps people answer your question) ;)
